# Search Multiple models in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still a beginner in ruby on rails and I'm trying to create a simple search option for a website that I'm developing.

I have number of models such as Sundries, Curry and Starter.

My search works fine if I have one model but how do I search all models title or name?

I have added following method to each of the models and tried to display results in home page. but no luck!

```
def self.search(search)
where("LOWER(title) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%") 
#where("content LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

Can someone please help me figure this out with an example please?

Thank you.

Comment: Based on your current approach I would do all the queries in your home page controller as instance variables. Then in your View loop over the results (i.e. loop over Sundries, then Curry, then Starter). Or you could re-write the query as a single one that joins the tables and checks all the options in the where clause.

Comment: _"I have number of models such as Sundries, Curry and Starter"_ – I'm curious, what are the differences between these models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add ActiveRecord_Relations together, and it will give you a simple array

```
@results = Sundries.search(search_term) + Curry.search(search_term) + Starter.search(search_term)
```

In the view...

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <%= "#{result.title} part of our fine #{result.class.name} choices" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: for this to work do the objects have to have the same attributes?

Comment: Only as far as necessary.  We know they all respond to `title` because OP has used `title` in all searches.  Any `link_to` should work as the `link_to` will adapt to the class of the object, so `link_to result` will link to `curry_path(result)` if result is an instance of the `Curry` class but it will link to `starter_path(result)` if result is a `Starter` instance.

Comment: That's great solution then IMO as long as the OP doesn't want to display more detailed information on the page.

Comment: @user3366016 You can automatically render a partial that will have different fields for different models... do `<%= render result %>` and if the result is a Curry it will look for a partial named `_curry.html.erb` .  It's explained in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 5):

Answering for anyone looking at this in 2019+... [scenic](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic) is the gem you want to use (as long as your database is postgres).

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches how you can implement this. You can use advanced search engines such as ElasticSearch or Sphinx. Or you can use (for example) [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem in case you are using Postgresql as your DataBase.

You can find RailsCasts for each of these approaches (some of them are probably for subscribers only).

As soon as you learning Rails, I would recommend to try out **pg_search** at first and avoid using search engines. Because it can be tricky sometimes for beginners. You can get to them later than you will have more data in your DB, or you would need to improve your skills. Try to make working solution in the first place and then improve it.

Comment: Creating a fulltext search like this in most cases is preferable to chaining models together as suggested by the other answers. This will allow you to do pagination and other limiting applications, which the other answers wouldn't be able to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) to implement search functionality.

In your view side

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, nil %>
<%= end %>
```

and in your controller action method,

```
q = params[:q]
@sunderies = Sundries.search(title_cont: q).result
@curry = Curry.search(title_cont: q).result
@starter = Starter.search(title_cont: q).result
@total_results = @sunderies + @curry + @starter
```